# Aurelia Custom attribute which changes the elements inner HTML

Tags: javascript, aurelia, custom-attribute

**Use Case**

I have a custom attribute which changes the content of the element it is attached, e.g. from non bold to bold.

**Problem**

With normal binding, the inner HTML does not get changed. I think, Aurelia is losing the binding as soon as the HTML is updated with "plain" Javascript.

You can see it in this GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=6f16ac1c8affb0277d7ad5c53d433482

Change the text in the area. There are five cases:

- Case 1: no attribute. Text updated. This is fine.
- Case 2: the text is not updated. Expected: update the text, but it should not be bold (missing value change call).
- Case 3: text is updated but not bold (missing value change call). This is fine.
- Case 4: text is not updated. Exptected: update text and make it bold
- Case 5: text is updated and made bold. This is fine.

**Question**

Can someone explain me, what is happing internally with case 2 and 4?

---

CODE:

app.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./bold-custom-attribute"></require>

  <textarea value.bind="content"></textarea>
  <pre>${content}</pre>
  <pre bold>${content}</pre>
  <pre bold textcontent.bind="content"></pre>
  <pre bold.bind="content">${content}</pre>
  <pre bold.bind="content" textcontent.bind="content"></pre>
</template>
```

bold-custom-attribute.js

```
export class BoldCustomAttribute {
  static inject = [Element];

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  bind() {
    //this.bolden(this.element);
  }

  attached() {
    this.bolden(this.element);
  }

  valueChanged(newValue, oldValue){
    this.bolden(this.element);
  }

  bolden(anElement) {
    anElement.innerHTML = '<b>' + anElement.innerText + '</b>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this at all rather than just binding a css class to the bound value?

Comment: @Paul in reality, `bolden()` is way more complex and not adding only one element. If it would only be strong text, then yes, you are right. But this is only a small reprodution.

Comment: Even still, modifying the `innerHTML` feels very non Aurelia (or any SPA framework for that matter). Could you not create a custom element that includes all the HTML you want, and then pass the content to it?

Comment: Sure, anyway the question is about what is the difference between those both cases, i.e. 4 and 5. One is working, one is not. So what is the difference internally?

Comment: Your custom-attribute is breaking the innerHTML observable. If you have complex rules you should encapsulate everything in a custom-element

Comment: @FabioLuz So what is the difference to `textcontent.bind`? Is it the following: `${content}` within the `<pre>` element is an observable on the `innerHTML` property of `<pre>` and `textcontent.bind` is an observable on the `textcontent` property of `<pre>`? But then, again, `<pre>` and it properties do not change, only the values, do they? Or is the observable of `${content}` on the node within `<pre>` and this gets lost by setting `innerHTML` of `<pre>` whereas `textcontent` is still observed as the property of `<pre>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out what is happening exactly by a combination of the post of Ashley, Fabio and the right place to debug.

The `${content}` string interpolations all get a `ChildInterpolationBinding` binding to the text node they form (which is within the `<pre>`, although not visible directly in e.g. Chrome Debugger), or more precisely to the `textContent` property.
This means, as soon as the inner HTML of the `<pre>` is replaced in `bolden()`, the text node disappears from the DOM (however, the binding is still there and updating the text nodes `textContent`). The new nodes have no binding of course (explaining why case 4 is not working).

Now, the differnce in case 5 (`textcontent.bind`) is that the `Binding` is directly attached to the `<pre>` it is specified on, or more precisely on the `pre.textContent` property. If the content within `<pre>` changes (e.g. via `textContent` or `innerHTML`), the binding is still on the correct node (`<pre>`).

**EDIT**
An important point here mentioned by Ashley is that the `textcontent` binding is called before the `valueChanged()`. This makes case 5 work at all. First, the `textcontent` is updated (with the binding which does not get lost), then, the value change is triggered reading in the just updated text content and applying the new HTML tags.

Because of this point, case 4 is working for one input change. After VM construction, the binding is correct and changing the value work. The interpolation binding is updating the text node, then `valueChanged()` is called and the text node with the bindings disappears from the DOM.

---

I was playing around a little bit, and managed to change the binding. **For sure, this should not be used in production.** When adding `created()`, everyhting works "fine".

```js
export class BoldCustomAttribute {
  static inject = [Element];

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  created(owningView, myView) {
    if (this.element.hasChildNodes() && this.element.firstChild.auInterpolationTarget === true) {
      owningView.bindings.forEach(binding => {
        if (binding.target === this.element.firstChild) {;
          binding.target = this.element;
          binding.targetProperty = 'innerHTML';
        }
      });
    }
  }

  bind() {
    this.bolden(this.element);
  }

  valueChanged(newValue, oldValue){
    this.bolden(this.element);
  }

  bolden(anElement) {
    anElement.innerHTML = '<b>' + anElement.innerText + '</b>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it not work if you have `BindingLanguage` injected in to the element?

Comment: Via constructor of the custom attribute? Yes, that works as well.

Comment: Then I would go with that instead of how you did it above.

Comment: I updated my post with an explanation based on your comment above for case 4 and 5 (order of binding calls). I think this pretty much explains all cases. And I removed the `BindingLanguage`. It was not needed at all.

Answer (score 2):

By modifying the HTML in the way you are, you cause new DOM elements to be created, and so Aurelia no longer has a reference to the DOM elements it needs to update bound values.

Comment: Altough your answer may be right, it is not completely satisfying to me :). Why is e.g. case 5 working? The HTML is added there as well. How is case 4 bound in Aurelia? Isn't it bound to the outer HTML (`<pre>`) which is not changed?

Comment: Case 5 works because you bound the attribute to `content`, so Aurelia calls `valueChanged` on the attribute, but it seems to happen after `textContent` is updated. Basically, Case 5 works due to luck of Aurelia updating `textContent` before it calls `valueChanged`.

Comment: As far as why Case 4 doesn't work, I'm not sure. Jeremy Danyow might be able to explain. I'll point him to the question. All of that being said, I agree with the comments posted to the question by @MarcScheib and FabioLuz, in so much as it feels like whatever you are trying to accomplish, this is the incorrect strategy for successfully accomplishing it.

Comment: Pinging @FabioLuz about my comment above

Comment: Interesting point for case 5. I could not find a binding within the `owningView` as for the others (there is only one for the textarea if I remove the `textcontent.bind`). So, there must be something else happening internally.

Comment: lol, I'm an idiot and just realized I typed your name instead of @powerbuoy on my previous comment